# Drawing bearing from an aircraft

Tags: bearing, radar

I have a table which records the position of the aircraft and a line of bearing to an emitter - so the use case is (imagine.....) i don't know where London Heathrow airport is but I know the signal the air traffic radar transmits; I fly towards it from Cardiff airport.  At known times I strike a line of bearing from the nose of the aircraft to Heathrow - as I move towards Heathrow in the respective air lanes, the lines start to cross indicating the position of Heathrow.  Hand wavy moment:  so an 10.00 its around 2oclock, at 10:30 its around 3oclock and then we fly overhead the M1 motorway and Heathrow is on the nose of the aircraft.  If I draw those three lines, they intersect at Heathrow. The table looks something like:

```
Time, Lat, Long, Height, Roll, Pitch, Emitter Bearing from ac nose

1000, 123, 123, 10,000m, 0,  4 up, 30 right

1030, 134, 134, 9,000m,  0,  0   , 90 right <new line>

1045, 145, 145, 3,000m,  0,  0,  , 0 nose
```

I hope to make something like:

[image]

Very new to GIS. How can I do this?

Comment: Does your table extract correspond to the image? Because for the second aircraft drawing, the emitter is actually not at 90° to the right of the aircraft, right?

Comment: Take a look at this post (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256738/bearing-of-two-close-lines-in-python). Maybe it will help you out finding a solution for your problem.